# Setting anonymous function scope of 'this' in jQuery utility / ajax methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, anonymous-function

As noted in [this blog post](http://www.dustindiaz.com/scoping-anonymous-functions/) you can set the scope of `this` in an anonymous function in Javascript.

Is there a more elegant way of scoping `this` in the anonymous function call on `success` of the AJAX request (i.e. not using `that`)?

For example:

```
var Foo = {

  bar: function(id) {

    var that = this;

    $.ajax({
      url: "www.somedomain.com/ajax_handler",
      success: function(data) {
        that._updateDiv(id, data);
      }
    });

  },

  _updateDiv: function(id, data) {

    $(id).innerHTML = data;

  }

};

var foo = new Foo;
foo.bar('mydiv');
```

Using call but still have to name the parent object scope `that`.

```
success: function(data) {
    (function() {
      this._updateDiv(id, data);
    }).call(that);
}
```

Comment: The `that=this` pattern is elegant, it is also simple, and (being a common pattern) recognizable. Don't fight it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In jQuery 1.4 you have the [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method, you can simply write:

```
 //...
 bar: function(id) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "someurl",
      success: $.proxy(this, '_updateDiv')
    });
  },
  //...
```

`$.proxy` takes an object, that will be used as the `this` value and it can take either a string (a member of that object) or a function, and it will return a new function that will always have a particular scope.

Another alternative is the `bind` function, now part of the ECMAScript Fifth Edition standard is the best:

```
//...
  bar: function(id) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "someurl",
      success: function(data) {
        this._updateDiv(id, data);
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
//...
```

This function will be available natively soon, when JavaScript engines fully implement the ES5 standard, for now, you can use the following 8-line long implementation:

```
// The .bind method from Prototype.js 
if (!Function.prototype.bind) { // check if native implementation available
  Function.prototype.bind = function(){ 
    var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        object = args.shift(); 
    return function(){ 
      return fn.apply(object, 
        args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))); 
    }; 
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess this question is more about personal taste. I like the bind method. I am enlightened.

Answer (score 6):

The [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function provides a concise means of doing this already in the form of the *context* parameter:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "www.somedomain.com/ajax_handler",
  context: this,
  success: function(data) {
    this._updateDiv(id, data);
  }
});
```

Though the techniques [CMS outlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128251/setting-anonymous-function-scope-of-this-in-jquery-utility-ajax-methods/2128296#2128296) are more suitable for general use.

Comment: This is the preferable approach. It's not only _much_ clearer, but it's healthier for GC since it does not create a closure like `$.proxy` so if you're making a large amount of requests that's an extra onus..