# Preserving the function's scope when using function.apply(...)

Tags: javascript

Consider the following example:

```
var funcToCall = function() {...}.bind(importantScope);

// some time later
var argsToUse = [...];
funcToCall.apply(someScope, argsToUse);
```

I want to preserve 'importantScope' of funcToCall. Yet, I need to use apply to apply an unknown number of arguments. 'apply' requires that I provide 'someScope'. I don't want to change the scope, I just want to apply the arguments to the function and preserve its scope. How would I do that?

Comment: Yes it is: it's standardized in ECMAScript 5.

Comment: I'm using the Prototype framework.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought (sorry for the deleted comment). I figured the OP wasn't talking about [JavaScript 1.8.5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) - not currently supported by any of the major browsers.

Comment: In other words: Is it possible to find the scope object of a function?

Comment: @Nick: did you even try this simple example yourself? `funcToCall` stays bound to `importantScope` no matter what you pass to `apply`.

Comment: @Crescent As I rule, I need to understand the code I'm planning to use, unless I trust the author. Running the code that I wrote and seeing that importantScope remains wouldn't have improved my understanding of _why_ it works. In my experience, saying "hmm it works, moving on" is a sure way to have one bitch of a bug to catch two weeks later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass any old object (including `null`) as the first argument to the `apply()` call and `this` will still be `importantScope`.

```
function f() {
    alert(this.foo);
}

var g = f.bind( { foo: "bar"} );

g(); // Alerts "bar"
g.apply(null, []); // Alerts "bar"
```

The `bind` method creates a new function in which the `this` value is guaranteed to be the object you passed in as the parameter to the `bind` call. Regardless of how this new function is called, `this` will always be the same. A simple implementation would look like this (note the implementation specified ECMAScript 5 and that in Prototype does more than this but this should give you the idea):

```
Function.prototype.bind = function(thisValue) {
    var f = this;
    return function() {
        return f.apply(thisValue, arguments);
    };
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "any old object" if I pass an object to apply, that object will become the scope. Wouldn't it? By the time the call is being made I no longer have access to "importantScope"

Comment: @Bears Passing null binds the global object as the scope. I want to "preserve" the scope, whatever it was.

Comment: A function created by `bind` will have the `this` value you bound to it, no matter how it's called. It might help to see an implementation of `Function.prototype.bind`. I'll add one to my answer.

Comment: Indeed it does, now I'm confused on why that is. Can you shed some light? {} is supposed to be made 'this' inside g. {} doesn't have a property foo, yet this works. Why is that? Wouldn't that mean that the docs here are not accurate: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: The implementation of bind answers the question for me. Thank you.

Comment: The original function and the function returned by calling its `bind` method are different objects. The "bound" function can be seen as a wrapper that calls the original function with the `this` value specified in the bind call while making no use at all of its own value of this.

Comment: Note this lightweight implementation of `Function#bind` doesn't have partial application, so it's not ECMAScript Fifth Edition compliant. Prototype's implementation [eg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128251#2128296) is complete.

Comment: Good point. The plan was just to illustrate the general idea of `bind` but I should have made that clear. I'll update my answer.